# Qt Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have `mainwindow` class with such slots in it:

```
void MainWindow::connect_to_server(const std::string& nickname,
                                   const std::string& ip, 
                                   int port)
{

    remote_server = new Server(nickname, ip, port);

    connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(error()), SLOT(connection_failed()));

    auto thread = new QThread(this);
    remote_server->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), remote_server, SLOT(establish_connection()));
    connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(stop_thread()), thread, SLOT(quit()));

    thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::action_disconnect_triggered() {
    if (remote_server == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    remote_server->disconnect();
    remote_server = nullptr;
}
```

And `Server` class:

```
void Server::establish_connection() {
    master_socket = std::move(
                std::unique_ptr<QTcpSocket>(new QTcpSocket(nullptr))
                );

    master_socket->connectToHost(ip.c_str(), port);
    master_socket->waitForConnected(timeout*1000);

    if (master_socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState) {
        disconnect();
        emit error();
    }

    emit stop_thread();
}

void Server::disconnect() {
    if (master_socket) {
        master_socket->disconnectFromHost();
    }
}
```

Initially, I invoke `MainWindow::connect_to_server` where client successfully connected to remote server. Then, I invoke `MainWindow::action_disconnect_triggered` and on this stage I get such error:

[image]

Btw, when I run it in OS X 10.11, error does not emerge and all works properly. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: disconnectFromHost probably can only be called by the thread of affinity of the socket.

Comment: The title is flat out wrong: You most definitely *can* send `QEvents` to objects in any thread. So that's not your problem. Please minimize your code and amend the title to match the real issue.

Answer (score 3):

`remote_server->disconnect();` might be the issue here.

you do not send the event directly, but you call the function and it gets invoked in your main thread.

try `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(remote_server, "disconnect", Qt::QueuedConnection);` to see if this problem still exists

cheers

Comment: Now error doesn't appear but socket does not disconnected. Also Qt prints `QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method Server::disconnect()`

Comment: as long as the object remains in the thread, you should only comunicate with it via slots

Comment: I've made `Server::disconnect()` as slot, but now condition `if (master_socket) ...` always false and `master_socket->disconnectFromHost()` never occurs.

Comment: `disconnect` is wrong! You need to call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(remote_server, "disconnectFromHost", Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting the objects before moving to thread. That way Qt cant find it in the new one. Just move to thrrqd before everything and this should work.

Comment: I make so https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a2e48df45ea305daebc0 but error still appears.